# Cannot create datawindow with postgresql stored procedure in PowerBuilder

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, powerbuilder

I'm currently running PowerBuilder 2021 Build 1311 and PostgreSQL 13.8. I can't create a new datawindow with postgresql stored procedure in PowerBuilder.
I go to File --> New--> Select any datawindow --> Stored procedure
--> select Procedure and click Next --> Ok, The Following Error Occurs.

Cannot Create DataWindow.
SQLSTATE = 42883.
Error : sp_employee is a procedure. Error while executing  a query.

### Procedure code:(Simple Code)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.sp_employee(
    )
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
begin
Select * from employee;
end
$BODY$;
```

The stored procedure works fine in pgadmin, but it doesn't work in PowerBuilder.

Does powerbuilder support postgresql stored procedure for a source of a datawindow?

Comment: Procedures are not meant to return results in Postgres. Use a set-returning function instead.

Comment: "*The stored procedure works fine in pgadmin*" - no it does not. It will fail with "*ERROR: query has no destination for result data*"